# How is table with code formatted incorrectly?

Tags: support, bug, code-formatting, formatting, tables

Why is this table not formatted correctly?

| Base (base) | Exponent (exp) | `Math.pow(base, exp)` | `numeral(n).format('0[.]00e+0')` | `logFormatter(n, base)` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | -5 | 0.000009999999999999999 | 10e-6 | 1 x 10⁻⁵ |
| 10 | -2.445 | 0.0035892193464500534 | 3.59e-3 | 3.59 x 10⁻³ |
| 10 | -1 | 0.1 | 1e-1 | 1 x 10⁻¹ |
| 10 | 0 | 1 | 1e+0 | 1 x 10⁻⁰ |
| 10 | 1 | 10 | 1e+1 | 1 x 10¹ |
| 10 | 2.545 | 350.75187395256796 | 3.51e+2 | 3.51 x 10² |
| 10 | 5 | 100000 | 1e+5 | 1 x 10⁵ |
| 2 | -5 | 0.03125 | 3.13e-2 | 1 x 2⁻⁵ |
| 2 | -2.445 | 0.18364607915978864 | 1.84e-1 | 1.47 x 2⁻³ |
| 2 | -1 | 0.5 | 5e-1 | 1 x 2⁻¹ |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 1e+0 | 1 x 2⁻⁰ |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 2e+0 | 1 x 2¹ |
| 2 | 2.545 | 5.836081376960701 | 5.84e+0 | 1.46 x 2² |
| 2 | 5 | 32 | 3.20e+1 | 1 x 2⁵ |
| `Math.E` | -5 | 0.006737946999085469 | 6.74e-3 | 1 x e⁻⁵ |
| `Math.E` | -2.445 | 0.08672613490173116 | 8.67e-2 | 1.74 x e⁻³ |
| `Math.E` | -1 | 0.36787944117144233 | 3.68e-1 | 1 x e⁻¹ |
| `Math.E` | 0 | 1 | 1e+0 | 1 x e⁻⁰ |
| `Math.E` | 1 | 2.718281828459045 | 2.72e+0 | 1 x e¹ |
| `Math.E` | 2.545 | 12.743228086065521 | 1.27e+1 | 1.72 x e² |
| `Math.E` | 5 | 148.41315910257657 | 1.48e+2 | 1 x e⁵ |

Somehow I can post this table here in the meta SO just fine but I get this error in regular SO.

The error is

> Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

[image]

Comment: Looks like a bug to me...

Comment: Most likely a bug, the misformatted code detection is just a heuristic and it might miss cases. The simple workaround is to post less data in the table.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I am trying to use this table on this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66072520/exponential-number-formatter-javascript/66072630#66072630 to no avail, resorting to a picture of the table above . But yet when I tried to open this meta issue, it works perfectly fine. BTW the regular SO formats the table just fine in the preview, just doesn't let me complete the review.

Comment: This issue had been resolved

Comment: "table with code" may or may not refer to `Math.pow(base, exp)` and `numeral(n).format('0[.]00e+0')`